# In AWS, How to specify region in describe-image api to get AMI Id for that region

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I am finding it too hard to specify the region in the `describe-image` api of AWS java SDK.
I am filtering out the result using `Filter()` but there is no way (or I can't find one) to specify a particular region to get AMI ids of that particular region and hence, it always results in "The image id '[ami-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx]' does not exist".

How can I get AMI ids for a particular region.

Following is the Code I am using currently

```
final AmazonEC2 ec2 = AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion('us-east-1').build();

DescribeImagesRequest request = new DescribeImagesRequest().withOwners("amazon");
request.getFilters().add(new Filter().withName("name").withValues("*centos*7*"));
request.getFilters().add(new Filter().withName("is-public").withValues("true"));
request.getFilters().add(new Filter().withName("manifest-location").withValues(""));

DescribeImagesResult result = ec2.describeImages(request);
```

I am using the first Image returned after sorting by recent images and I was assuming I have specified the region in `ec2Client` it should return AMIs of that region but it always throws the error.

How, Can I get the AMI ids for a particular region?

Comment: Can you provide an example of an AMI that is incorrectly returned?

Answer (score 0):

With the exception of AWS IAM and AWS CloudFront, all **AWS services are regional**.

Therefore, information returned will always be limited to resources in the region requested.

You are correct that it will only return values for AMIs in the region specified in the `ec2Client`.

Here is an equivalent query for the AWS CLI:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owners amazon --filters 'Name=name,Values=*centos*7' --query 'Images[].[ImageId,Name]' --region us-east-1
```

I realize that you are seeking a Centos image, but it is worth mentioning that the latest Amazon Linux and Windows AMIs can be obtained from the Parameter Store: [Query for the latest Amazon Linux AMI IDs using AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/query-for-the-latest-amazon-linux-ami-ids-using-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/)